# Is it possible to write a function template which returns whether the number of arguments is divisible by N?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I've been learning about variadic templates, and with the help of [this excellent blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/), I've managed to write a function template `even_number_of_args` which returns whether the number of arguments it receives is divisible by 2.

```
#include <iostream>

bool even_number_of_args() {
    return true;
}

template <typename T>
bool even_number_of_args(T _) {
    return false;
}

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Vs>
bool even_number_of_args(T _, U __, Vs... vs) {
  return even_number_of_args(vs...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << even_number_of_args()                   << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << even_number_of_args(1)                  << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << even_number_of_args(1, "two")           << std::endl; // true
    std::cout << even_number_of_args(1, "two", 3.0)      << std::endl; // false
    std::cout << even_number_of_args(1, "two", 3.0, '4') << std::endl; // true
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to write a function template that takes, as a template argument, a number `N` and returns whether the number of arguments it receives is a multiple of `N`. For example, the function may look something like this:

```
number_of_args_divisible_by_N<1>(1, "two", 3.0, '4'); // true
number_of_args_divisible_by_N<2>(1, "two", 3.0, '4'); // true
number_of_args_divisible_by_N<3>(1, "two", 3.0, '4'); // false
number_of_args_divisible_by_N<4>(1, "two", 3.0, '4'); // true
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Yes, it's as simple as

```
template<int N, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool number_of_args_divisible_by(Ts&&...)
{
    return sizeof...(Ts) % N == 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can return a more metaprogramming-friendly type:

```
template<int N, typename... Ts>
constexpr integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Ts) % N == 0>
number_of_args_divisible_by(Ts&&...)
{
    return {};
}
```

Comment: General FYI: the return value is a compile time constant.

Comment: `std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Ts) % N == 0>` would be a better return type in my opinion.  :)

Comment: I think it could be a little more confusing to people unfamiliar with C++ metaprogramming idioms. I'll edit it in as an alternative, though.

Comment: For C++11 compatibility, put the return type in place of `auto`, and `return {};`  (Your version is C++14)  Also golfs off 4 characters.  ;)

Comment: I agree about golf and C++11, but it's much less aesthetically pleasant to the eye ;)

Comment: I find it strange that the blog post didn't mention `sizeof...`

Comment: Can you show how you can bind this function to a pointer, pass it somewhere and call it, so that it knows its number of arguments and calculates the right answer?

Answer (score 27):

Although krzaq's solution is pretty good, I think that implementing the "magic" behind `sizeof...` can serve as an interesting learning exercise.

It uses a technique that is very common to template meta-programming - a non-template function covering the base case, and a template function that reduces the problem by one step:

```
// Base case
int count_args() {
    return 0;
}
// Reduction
template<typename T, typename... Vs>
int count_args(T _, Vs... vs) {
    return 1 + count_args(vs...);
}
```

With this functionality in place, you can implement divisibility checker using the approach from krzaq's answer:

```
template<int N,typename... Vs>
bool is_arg_divisible(Vs... vs) {
    return count_args(vs...) % N == 0;
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/kB3CXv)

Comment: I believe that `sizeof ...` must be using less "compliation" cycles compared to the trick you mentioned. Hence it's always recommended to use `sizeof...` even for learning purpose. :-)

Comment: I would add that this is the basic foundation for functional programming as well: providing a base case and make so that the other case rely on recursion down to it.

Comment: This generates template instantiation recursions.  Compilers are free to limit this, and generally do at around 1000.  Built-in stuff like `sizeof...` or even on some compilers `make_index_sequence<N>` bypass this limit, and are more performant to boot.  You can implement log-depth `make_index_sequence` and probably even `is_arg_divisible` with a bunch of work: the pattern above is at best a toy pattern for learning and small cases (not suitable for a library), even if you have a problem with no built-in.

Comment: I believe you could implement `sizeof_dot_dot_dot` like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/I5FbbGsC5CSQPbIy) with no recursion at all. I'm not sure if the character array is guaranteed to be optimized out, but both gcc and clang have no problems with it [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/cAIjLO).

Comment: @Yakk Of course! I think your points are very much self-explanatory: after all, nothing beats built-in "magic" of a compiler. The reason I added this answer is to illustrate a fundamental recursive technique, which is a simplified version of OP's example.

Comment: @Yakk it seems reasonable that if you have access to the C++11 notation of `Vs... vs`, then you also have access to `constexpr`.  We just need to add that to the function call.

Comment: @CortAmmon I don't understand how your response applies to the comment you are responding to.  Limits on template instantiation depth have little to nothing to do with `constexpr`.

Comment: @Yakk You're right.  I focused too much on the word "recursions" and managed to misread your performance questions as being questions about run-time performance.  Feel free to ignore my comment.